# Flutter with Socket.io

Tags: node.js, android-studio, flutter, dart, socket.io

I have tried to use socket.io with flutter. But I get the following error.

```
D/FlutterSocketIoPlugin: SocketIO( 6279): reconnect_attempt: [108]
D/FlutterSocketIoPlugin: SocketIO( 6279): reconnecting: [108]
D/FlutterSocketIoPlugin: SocketIO( 6279): connect_error: [{"cause":{"detailMessage":"CLEARTEXT communication to 10.0.2.2 not permitted by network security policy","stackTrace":[],"suppressedExceptions":[]},"detailMessage":"websocket error","stackTrace":[],"suppressedExceptions":[]}]
```

I wrote the server using nodejs.

```
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const socketio = require('socket.io');
const { Socket } = require('dgram');
const formatMessage = require('./utils/messages');
const {userJoin, getCurrentUser, userLeave, getRoomUsers} = require('./utils/users');

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketio(server);

const botName = 'ChatCordBot';

//run when client connects
io.on('connection', socket=>{

    socket.on('joinroom',({username, room})=>{

        const user = userJoin(socket.id, username, room);

        socket.join(user.room);

        socket.emit('message',formatMessage(botName,'Welcome to chatcord!'));

        //broadcast
        socket.broadcast.to(user.room).emit('message',formatMessage(botName,`${user.username} has joined`));

        //send users and room info
        io.to(user.room).emit('roomusers',{
            room:user.room,
            users:getRoomUsers(user.room)
        });
    }); 

    // Listen for chatMessage
    socket.on('chatMessage', msg => {
        // const user = getCurrentUser(socket.id);

        // io.to(user.room).emit('message', formatMessage(user.username, msg));
        console.log(msg);
    });

    //runs when client disconnects
    socket.on('disconnect',()=>{

        const user = userLeave(socket.id);

        if(user){
            io.to(user.room).emit('message',formatMessage(botName,`${user.username} has left the chat`));

            //send users and room info
            io.to(user.room).emit('roomusers',{
                room:user.room,
                users:getRoomUsers(user.room)
            });
        }
    });
});

const PORT = 3000;

server.listen(PORT,()=>{console.log(`Listening to ${PORT}`)});
```

Here is part of the client side where I used socket.io.

```
import 'package:flutter_socket_io/flutter_socket_io.dart';
import 'package:flutter_socket_io/socket_io_manager.dart';


class Body extends StatefulWidget {
  const Body({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _BodyState createState() => _BodyState();
}

class _BodyState extends State<Body> {
  SocketIO socketIO;
  @override
  // ignore: must_call_super
  void initState(){
    initSocketIO();
  }

  initSocketIO(){
    socketIO = SocketIOManager().createSocketIO('http://10.0.2.2:3000', '/');
    socketIO.init();

    socketIO.subscribe('chatMessage', getMessage);

    socketIO.connect();

  }

  getMessage(){
    if(socketIO != null){
      print("socket is not null");
    }
  }
```

I'm running my flutter app using the android emulator in android stuudio. Is that the cause for the error?
Or is there some error in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set use the cleartext traffic property to true in your AndroidManifest file, like below.

```
<application
....
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
....>
```